# Replace double quotes with backslash plus double quotes within JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

Suppose I have this simple JSON:

```
{"test":"test"}
```

Now I want to convert it into the following format:

```
{\"test\":\"test\"}
```

I have found some of the solutions of replacing double quotes with backslash and double quotes but all those works on text format.

I need to pass this kind of format to AWS SNS as message parameter.

Comment: could try JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({"test":"test"}));

Comment: 1. This is a plain old object not JSON; 2. `'{"test":"test"}'` would be [JSON](http://json.org); 3. Why you think you have to escape the quotes? 4. Just send the JSON (from 2.) via POST

Comment: If you have found methods to work on text then just serialize your JSON object (using stringify or something similar) and perform your solutions on the JSON serialised string.

Comment: @Andreas 1. I think the AWS SNS use JSON format, but you can't use an object inside 'message' parameter, so the trick is to encode the json (inside the json packet) and then decode it client side. 2. the OP said JSON object not JSON.

Comment: @Andreas when i sent simple json object to AWS SNS by JSON.stringify() method it gave me error.So i need to encode the json

Comment: @Hacketo: I see... So the actual question should be more like: "How to pass custom payload as message to AWS SNS" - Then this question is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845984/how-to-send-extra-parameters-in-payload-via-amazon-sns-push-notification

Comment: @Duncan when i do JSON.stringify() it will come up as {"test":"test"} in text format but this is not acceptable in SNS

Comment: @Andreas But in that question they send request to SNS through PHP but i want it in javascript. So it may br useful for those who have same problem but in PHP

Answer (score 3):

You may convert the JSON object to a string format first by using JSON.stringify()

```
var temp = {"test":"test"};
var tempStr = JSON.stringify(temp);
console.log(tempStr); //> {"test":"test"}
var modifiedStr = tempStr.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
console.log(modifiedStr); //> {\"test\":\"test\"}
```

If your want to just encode only the open and close double quote, you may try this

```
var temp = {"test":'te"st'};
var tempObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp));

for(var k in tempObj){
    tempObj[k]=tempObj[k].replace(/"/g, "<DOUBLE_QUOTES_4594>");
}

var tempStr = JSON.stringify(tempObj);  
console.log(tempStr); //> {"test":"te<DOUBLE_QUOTES_4594>st"}

var modifiedStr = tempStr.replace(/"|"/g, '\\"').replace(/<DOUBLE_QUOTES_4594>/g, '"');
console.log(modifiedStr); //> {\"test\":\"te"st\"}
```

Comment: I am not sure what format AWS SNS accepts, please tell me if you know.

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested in comment
You can go from a `Javascript object` to an `escaped JSON` using `JSON.stringify` twice

```
var myObject = {"test":"test"};

var myJson = JSON.stringify(myObject); // {"test":"test"}

var myEscapedJson = JSON.stringify(myJson); // "{\"test\":\"test\"}"
```